# Windows Forms - adding new row to a data-bound data

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, visual-studio-2012

I have a `Windows Form` with dgv. For now it's just for presentational purposes so I use dummy data to populate one row with data. I also have a button named `Add New Row` which for just have to add new empty row in the `dataGridView` every time it's clicked. For the initial populating of the dgv I use the `load` event of the form like this :

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

    MyData td13 = new MyData();

    td13.colorCombinationColumn = "aff";

    td13.remarksColumn = "abcdddd";

    td13.prodColumn = true;

    td13.LastModifiedColumn = "ab";

    td13.ByColumn = "abc";

    MyData[] arr = new MyData[2];
    arr[0] = td13;

    dataGridView1.DataSource = arr;

}
```

Where `MyData` is this class :

```
public class MyData
{
    private int mId;

    private string mCombination;

    private string mremarks;

    private bool mprod;

    private string mLastModified;

    private string mBefore;


    public int Id
    {
        get
        {
            return mId;
        }

        set
        {
            ...
```

So far so good, but then I add my button and handle his `click` event:

```
private void btnAddRow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SoleData[] arr = new SoleData[1];
    dataGridView1.DataSource = arr;
}
```

And here is where the things go wrong. If I just `dataGridView1.Rows.Add(1);` is says `Rows cannot be programmatically added to the DataGridView's rows collection when the control is data-bound.`. As you see I tried some other approaches but so far no success.

Comment: Don't bind to `Array`, use `BindingList`

Comment: What is the relationship between the MyData class and SoleData?

Comment: Mistake in the code I edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use a `BindingList<MyData>` instead of the `MyData[] arr`.
Any modifications you do to the list will be reflected in the DGV, no further code necessary.
(Also, declare the list as a private field of the form.)